# Running Git Log from Bash only Executes first line of script

Tags: git, batch-file

I am attempting to get a log of the commits, by using `git log` and outputting it into a csv file.
I've set up the formatting to my liking, but instead of having to remember each flag, I want to run the command from a script, which also allows me to include headers in the csv

```
git log --date=local --pretty=format:%H,%an,%ae,%as,%s  >> commitLog.csv
```

produces the correct output when run in the gitBash, but when combined in a `.bat` file only the header line executes

```
echo hash, contributor,email, date, message > commitLog.csv
git log --date=local --pretty=format:%H,%an,%ae,%as,%s  >> commitLog.csv
```

this produces the csv with only the titles. I am not sure what I am missing, I've attempted to add thing such as `unset GIT_DIR` and `CALL` and `env -i`

**EDIT**
when running the git log command on its own from a .bat file, the csv is empty, but must've executed the >> `commitLog.csv` portion as the file is created

Comment: First step I'd try is to double each `%` as `%` has a special meaning to batch, and its escape character is another `%`.

Comment: negative on that solution but that does seem logical @Magoo

Comment: I'd go with @Magoo's suggestion too. Did you do it like this? **1.** ```@(Echo hash,contributor,email,date,message```, **2.** ```git.exe log --date=local --pretty=format:%%H,%%an,%%ae,%%as,%%s) 1>"commitLog.csv"```

Comment: Which is this now, Windows `batch-file` or are you running this in a Linux shell script? I ask because of the shebang `#!/bin/bash` and `shell`, `bash` tags.

Comment: Batch files don't support shebangs and don't use shell syntax.

Comment: removed but still no result @knittl

Comment: apologies, it was indeed a Batch file, I did also attempt it with a .sh hence the shebang

Comment: @Compo this now works when ran as a .sh and not .bat

Comment: @Compo as a .bat file your solution only produces the header row

Comment: @Xray25, as the redirection and closing parenthesis is on the second line, that could only be as a result of your `git` command failing, or outputting to stdErr. Perhaps you should change it to: ```"P:\athTo\git.exe" log --date=local --pretty=format:%%H,%%an,%%ae,%%as,%%s) 1>"P:\athTo\commitLog.csv" 2>CON``` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was solved using the comments above from @Gerhard, @Compo and @Magoo.

Double `%%` and the use of `.sh` instead of `.bat`